# Как сделать авторизацию/регистрацию на WordPress?

Tags: php, wordpress, веб-программирование

Как сделать авторизацию и регистрацию на WordPress и где вообще хранятся данные с форм?

Comment: Регистрация и авторизация в ВП из коробки. А все данные хранятся в базе.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Попробуйте [это:](http://aimblog.ru/ustanovka/plaginy-wordpress/plagin-profile-builder.html)

1. Итак, сначала скачивает и активируем плагин Profile Builder.
2. Дальше нужно создать новую страницу. Потом идем в настройки плагина: Админка — Пользователи — Profile Builder — стандартные поля профиля. Здесь, с помощью кнопок убираем лишние поля со страницы регистрации. И также указываем те поля, которые нужно заполнять обязательно.
3. Теперь нужно сделать форму авторизации (форму, где уже зарегистрированный пользователь будет вводить логин и пароль).  Форму авторизации сделаем в сайдбаре через виджет «Текст». Добавляем в сайдбар в нужное место новый виджет «Текст» где вставляем шорткод [wppb-login]. Называем виджет «Авторизация на сайте».

Comment: Ну фигня же, может парень разработчик и хочет кодировать код)

Comment: @Krya Любишь кодить код - люби и с графической работать) В любом случае, это должно решить его проблему.

Comment: Спасибо, но ещё один вопрос. А вообще есть альтернатива базе данных на вордпрессе?

Comment: @Asen123 Данные о пользователях хранятся в таблицах {prefix}_users, {prefix}_usermeta

Comment: @Asen123 Посмотрите это: https://webliberty.ru/baza-dannyih-wordpress-ee-struktura-i-tablitsyi/. И если мой ответ помог вам, отметьте его галочкой, чтобы другие участники видели, что проблема решена ;)